# Sliding from one screen to another in a webapp

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, web-applications

I am writing a webapp that's designed to target both iPhone and android. The app has a main menu screen with a list of options the user can choose from. When they tap one of these options I would like the main menu to slide off the left and the screen for the selected option to slide in the right.

Does anyone know of any libraries (e.g. jQuery plugins) that would help achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile is still in beta but it has neat mobile app features like this in pretty good working order.

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I want. It does have an annoying visual glitch though in that it jumps to the top of the page before a slide transition.